# Azure: How to create an Event subscription programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-eventgrid

I have many storage accounts that are created programmatically, and I'd like to create an event subscription in each to listen to `BlobCreated` events with an existing Azure Function endpoint. Right now, I'm doing this manually by going to the portal, but it's been time-consuming to say the least.

Are there any C# code examples that would create an event subscription using Azure credentials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find an example in [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/event-grid-dotnet-publish-consume-events/blob/542f038d5793528b75e1a2c9f992c0951cfd0bd5/EGManageArmEventSubscriptions/EGManageArmEventSubscriptions/Program.cs#L121)

```
    static async Task CreateEventGridEventSubscriptionAsync(string azureSubscriptionId, string eventSubscriptionName, EventGridManagementClient eventGridMgmtClient)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Creating an event subscription to Azure subscription {azureSubscriptionId} with destination as queue {QueueName} under storage account {StorageAccountId}");

        string scope = $"/subscriptions/{azureSubscriptionId}";

        EventSubscription eventSubscription = new EventSubscription()
        {
            Destination = new StorageQueueEventSubscriptionDestination()
            {
                ResourceId = StorageAccountId,
                QueueName = QueueName
            },
            // The below are all optional settings
            EventDeliverySchema = EventDeliverySchema.EventGridSchema,
            Filter = new EventSubscriptionFilter()
            {
                IsSubjectCaseSensitive = false,
                SubjectBeginsWith = "",
                SubjectEndsWith = ""
            }
        };

        EventSubscription createdEventSubscription = await eventGridMgmtClient.EventSubscriptions.CreateOrUpdateAsync(scope, eventSubscriptionName, eventSubscription);
        Console.WriteLine("EventGrid event subscription created with name " + createdEventSubscription.Name);
    }
```

Please find the official documentation in [MS Docs - IEventSubscriptionsOperations Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.eventgrid.ieventsubscriptionsoperations?view=azure-dotnet)

[MS Docs - EventSubscriptionsOperationsExtensions.CreateOrUpdateAsync(IEventSubscriptionsOperations, String, String, EventSubscription, CancellationToken) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.eventgrid.eventsubscriptionsoperationsextensions.createorupdateasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_EventGrid_EventSubscriptionsOperationsExtensions_CreateOrUpdateAsync_Microsoft_Azure_Management_EventGrid_IEventSubscriptionsOperations_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Management_EventGrid_Models_EventSubscription_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

Comment: It looks like Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventGrid is now deprecated. (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventGrid)
And that Azure.ResourceManager.EventGrid should be used. The package can be found here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.EventGrid

But I can't find any examples of how to use it to create subscripions. Do you have any resources for that?