# Create an Event subscription programmatically Azure.ResourceManager.EventGrid

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventgrid

I have many storage accounts that are created programmatically, and I'd like to create an event subscription in each to listen to BlobCreated events with an existing Azure Function endpoint.

I can see [Azure: How to create an Event subscription programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65606705/azure-how-to-create-an-event-subscription-programmatically) with the Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventGrid package that is now deprecated.

The current package is Azure.ResourceManager.EventGrid, but I can not find an example of how to use it to create subscriptions.

For reference, I would like to achieve the equivalent as this CLI command:

```
az eventgrid event-subscription create \ 
--source-resource-id $storageid \
--name $subscription-name \
--endpoint $endpoint \
--subject-begins-with "/blobServices/default/containers/container/blobs/" \
--advanced-filter data.api StringIn CopyBlob PutBlob PutBlockList FlushWithClose CreateFile \
--advanced-filter data.contentLength NumberGreaterThan 0
```

Comment: You can make use of the samples here -https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.ResourceManager.EventGrid_1.0.1/sdk/eventgrid/Azure.ResourceManager.EventGrid/src/Generated/EventGridSubscriptionData.cs > Refer to the left side of the document for more samples.

Comment: I can not find any examples for creation, all I see is to get/retrieve elements

Answer (score 0):

I have referred this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/controlplane/event-subscriptions/create-or-update?view=rest-eventgrid-controlplane-2022-06-15&tabs=dotnet)  to create Azure Event Subscription with Azure Functions Destination using .Net:-

I have used Client Credentials flow for authentication, That uses Service Principal Client Id, Client secret and Tenant Id.

*Azure Eventgrid Trigger Function is required for creating Event subscription.*

**My Code:-**

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.EventGrid;
using Azure.ResourceManager.EventGrid.Models;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string tenantId = "xxxxxx2395";
        string clientId = "xxxxxxxx5cb";
        string clientSecret = "xxxxxxaQy";

        TokenCredential cred = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
        ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);

        

        string scope = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxe97cb2a7/resourceGroups/siliconRG/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/namespaces/siliconeventGrid";
        ResourceIdentifier scopeId = new ResourceIdentifier(string.Format("/{0}", scope));
        EventSubscriptionCollection collection = client.GetEventSubscriptions(scopeId);

       
        string eventSubscriptionName = "examplesubscription1";
        EventGridSubscriptionData data = new EventGridSubscriptionData()
        {
            Destination = new AzureFunctionEventSubscriptionDestination()
            {
                ResourceId = new ResourceIdentifier("/subscriptions/xxxxxxx2a7/resourceGroups/siliconRG/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/valleyfunc9/functions/EventGridTrigger1"),
            },
            Filter = new EventSubscriptionFilter()
            {
                SubjectBeginsWith = "ExamplePrefix",
                SubjectEndsWith = "ExampleSuffix",
                IsSubjectCaseSensitive = false,
            },
            DeadLetterDestination = new StorageBlobDeadLetterDestination()
            {
                ResourceId = new ResourceIdentifier("/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxx2a7/resourceGroups/siliconRG/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/siliconrgbdb7"),
                BlobContainerName = "contosocontainer",
            },
        };
        ArmOperation<EventSubscriptionResource> lro = await collection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, eventSubscriptionName, data);
        EventSubscriptionResource result = lro.Value;

        
        EventGridSubscriptionData resourceData = result.Data;
       
        Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded on id: {resourceData.Id}");
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

With **DefaultAzureCredentials** according to the Ms Document:-

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.EventGrid;
using Azure.ResourceManager.EventGrid.Models;


TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();

ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);




string scope = "/subscriptions/xxxxxa7/resourceGroups/siliconRG/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/namespaces/siliconeventGrid";
ResourceIdentifier scopeId = new ResourceIdentifier(string.Format("/{0}", scope));
EventSubscriptionCollection collection = client.GetEventSubscriptions(scopeId);


string eventSubscriptionName = "examplesubscription1";
EventGridSubscriptionData data = new EventGridSubscriptionData()
{
    Destination = new AzureFunctionEventSubscriptionDestination()
    {
        ResourceId = new ResourceIdentifier("/subscriptions/xxxxxb2a7/resourceGroups/siliconRG/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/valleyfunc9/functions/EventGridTrigger1"),
    },
    Filter = new EventSubscriptionFilter()
    {
        SubjectBeginsWith = "ExamplePrefix",
        SubjectEndsWith = "ExampleSuffix",
        IsSubjectCaseSensitive = false,
    },
    DeadLetterDestination = new StorageBlobDeadLetterDestination()
    {
        ResourceId = new ResourceIdentifier("/subscriptions/xxxxx7cb2a7/resourceGroups/siliconRG/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/siliconrgbdb7"),
        BlobContainerName = "contosocontainer",
    },
};
ArmOperation<EventSubscriptionResource> lro = await collection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, eventSubscriptionName, data);
EventSubscriptionResource result = lro.Value;


EventGridSubscriptionData resourceData = result.Data;

Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded on id: {resourceData.Id}");
```

Comment: In your code example, what would be `siliconeventGrid `? or general what should be the scope and how it related with the resource you want to create the subscription from?

Comment: siliconeventGrid is the name of the Event Grid namespace

Comment: If you see the example of the CLI command I only know the ID of the resource I want to create the subscription from. So, not sure what is the Event Grid namespace in that case. How does it know what is the source resource it will create the subscription?

Comment: For specific Resource refer this MS Doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/controlplane/event-subscriptions/create-or-update?view=rest-eventgrid-controlplane-2022-06-15&tabs=dotnet#eventsubscriptions_createorupdateforresource